# How to pass parameter data between templates in meteor flowlayout flowrouter

Tags: meteor, flowlayout

I have a template called : Orders which shows my orders collection of images :

```
{{#each images}}
<div class="images">
  <a href="/order/{{this._id}}"> <img class="image" src="{{this.url  }}"  /></a>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

No I want another tempate called order to show me only one item from collection that I click on: I try doing this way: 1. orders.js events for click on image:

```
"click .image": function() {
            Images.find({_id:this._id});
```

and orders.html:

```
<a href="/order/{{this._id}}"> <img class="image" src="{{this.url  }}"  /></a>
```

I also have routes.js :

```
FlowRouter.route("/orders", {                 **this part works fine**
                    action: function(){
                    FlowLayout.render("layout",{top:"orders", main:"test"});
                    }

  FlowRouter.route('/order/', {             **How do I do this part ????????**
                    action: function(){
                    FlowLayout.render("layout",{top:"order",data:image});

                    }
```

I used a dynamic layout template to show orders which shows fine.
How do I set the single order html , route and render ????

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

Beginning by your route, you should pass the id parameter in the path like that :

```
FlowRouter.route('/order/:imageId', {             
  action: function() {
    FlowLayout.render("layout",{ top: "order", main: "test" });
  }
});
```

Looking at the rendering on order.html file which contains the template order, something like:

```
<template name="order">
  {{#with image}}
    <!-- whatever you want to do -->
    <img src="{{url}}" />
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

This template uses order.js with a subscription to your collection for one image only and a helper called `image` which look for the parameter `imageId` you transmitted in your route via the function `FlowRouter.getParam`:

```
Template.order.onCreated(function() {
    var imageId = FlowRouter.getParam('imagedId');
    if ( imageId !== undefined ) {
      Meteor.subscribe('oneImage', imageId);
    }      
}

Template.order.helpers({
  image: function() {
    var imageId = FlowRouter.getParam('imagedId');
    if ( imageId !== undefined ) {
      return Images.findOne({ _id: imageId });
    }
  }
}
```

And to conclude, server side, you shall do a publication:

```
Meteor.publish('oneImage', function(imageId) {
  return Images.findOne({ _id: imageId });
}
```

Following this way, you don't need anymore your event `click .image` and you optimized your performance! ;)

Btw on orders.html in your `{{#each}}` loop, you don't need to write `{{this.url}}` nor `{{this._id}}`, `{{url}}` and `{{_id}}` are fine ;)

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve request parameter you can use:

```
FlowRouter.current().route._params.keys.id
```